# How to ignore spell check for specific language in sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3, spell-checking

Here is my settings

```
"dictionary": "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic",
"spell_check": true,
```

and it checks every languages.
it bothers me.

Answer (score 2):

Open a file of the type you don't want to spell check in and choose `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific` from the menu to open the settings specific to that kind of file. In those settings, set `spell_check` to `false` to turn it off for those kind of files.

Alternately, you can also turn off `spell_check` in your main settings and do this to turn it on only in the types of files where you want spell checking, if you mostly want it off and only occasionally want it on.

Comment: “In those settings, set spell_check to false”—how, please?

Comment: You literally add the text `"spell_check": false,` to the file. If you use the command mentioned to open the settings file, the file in the left hand side of the window will show you exactly the format of the file required.